# How to measure for how long a window is active?

Tags: wine, window-manager, productivity

I am a digital artist, using [Clip Studio Paint](https://www.clipstudio.net/en) (a Windows app) to draw, through [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). It would be interesting to know how many hours each piece takes me. But being how I am, most of the time I just forget to set up a chronometer to measure or to stop it after I end or during a break.

Would it be possible to have a script that logs how much time a window is active, so I can add that up and get a time?

EDIT: When I talk about the window being active, I specifically talk about the window being in focus, not just the program running, so that if I get distracted and alt-tab out I can get later a closer idea of how much I actually worked.

Comment: you could [edit] your question to include what you've mentioned in the comment to the answer below. Perhaps, clarify exactly what you mean by "active": your twitter example makes things quite complicated!

Comment: Script is very well possible, but how to distiguish the window? What is the wm class? Specific title etc?

Answer (score 2):

Each time you are launching a process a timer is launched, you can see it under `TIME+` using the `top` command

So if you want to know how long wine has been launch you can find the wine process on top or using this command `ps -aux | grep wine` it will be the time after the date

Comment: That is good to know! But I was wondering more specifically about just the time where the wine window is the active one. I don't want to also measure the forty minute gap I got distracted on twitter with the window open for example.

Comment: I suppose it depend on the way this application was build, what you should do is once your application is run is wine do a ps -aux | grep wine see the process, then open your new window in your application and do a ps -aux | grep again to see the new process running, it will be the one you are looking for